# Call a NSDictionary Value as Method

Tags: objective-c

How can I can I call a function which name I stored as a value an an NSDictionary? Basically I need to typecast a String as a method name/call. Is this possible?

```
[thisCellContent objectForKey:@"callFunction"] //the object contains the function name to be called

//call this value as function, something similar to this ..
[self [thisCellContent objectForKey:@"callFunction"]]
```

Is something like this possible?

Comment: By the way, this is not typecasting.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not like this, but you can use the runtime/reflection:

```
NSString *s = [thisCellContent objectForKey:@"callFunction"];
SEL sel = NSSelectorFromString(s);
[self performSelector:sel withObject:nil];
```

Comment: Apple documentation says that "The performSelector: method is equivalent to sending an aSelector message directly to the receiver".

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest putting an Objective-C block into the dictionary. You can then call the block (and it can call other things if you like). Something like this:

```
//In code that sets up the dictionary
void (^thingToCall)() = [^{ /* any code you want to run here */ } copy];
[dictionary setObject:thingToCall forKey:@"callFunction"];


//In code that uses the dictionary
void (^thingToCall)() = [dictionary objectForKey:@"callFunction"]; 
thingToCall(); //call the block
```

Comment: Note that the blocks will be leaked in the above.

Comment: Indeed, my snippets were probably a little over-brief. Normal Cocoa memory management rules apply.